# /dev/null questions

Tags: 18.04, files, root

so I was messing around with /dev/null mooving files to it like ...

```
sudo mv test /dev/null
```

and reading it ...

```
:~$ cat /dev/null
this is a file
:~$
```

but then I made another file with the file saying **this is another file**
and then I went a head and read /dev/null again before moving the new file to /dev/null by doing cat and this is what happened

```
:~$ cat /dev/null
:~$
```

can someone please explain to Me what is happening I'm on ubuntu 18.04.

thanks.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking how /dev/null got reinstated after you replaced it, right? If not, please clarify what you were expecting to happen.

Comment: What does `stat /dev/null` say *now*? I wonder if it's `cat`ing empty simply because another process wrote an empty *file* to it in the meantime, rather then because it somehow got reinstated as a character-special node

Comment: the first test file wasn't empty I appended the first file to it and then read it the 2 first parts were done after another so basicly the test file was written with **this is a file**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man null`:

```
NAME

       null, zero - data sink

DESCRIPTION

       Data written to the /dev/null and /dev/zero special files is discarded.

       Reads  from  /dev/null  always return end of file (i.e., read(2) returns 0), whereas reads
       from /dev/zero always return bytes containing zero ('\0' characters).

       These devices are typically created by:

           mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3
           mknod -m 666 /dev/zero c 1 5
           chown root:root /dev/null /dev/zero

FILES

       /dev/null
       /dev/zero

NOTES

       If these devices are not writable and readable for  all  users,  many  programs  will  act
       strangely.

       Since  Linux  2.6.31, reads from /dev/zero are interruptible by signals.  (This change was
       made to help with bad latencies for large reads from /dev/zero.)

SEE ALSO

       chown(1), mknod(1), full(4)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? I mean it seems like OP is asking what reinstated /dev/null after they replaced it, but the man page doesn't mention anything related.

Comment: OP trashed the required device file with his `sudo mv test /dev/null`. The `man` page explains why this is a Bad Idea, and what to do about it.

Comment: basicly what I needed as the answer is inside the description o man so yes it dose answer my question  (the part that i wanted is _reads from /dev/null always returns the end of the file_ )